# Fetch url via proxy on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an application on google-app-engine written in python. I want to fetch url via proxy from my application. I found two ways to fetch remote url from appengine:

1. Using [urlfetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/)
2. Using python built-in urllib2

Looking in documentation for urlfetch, i didn't found any way to set proxy. So i started to play with urllib2.
I've tried this:

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': "210.246.88.46:8080",})
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        resp = opener.open("http://whatsmyuseragent.com/", timeout=20)
        self.response.out.write(resp.read())
```

But looks like appengine ignores proxy and fetches url with its own ip. In result page ip of application is shown, and not ip of proxy.
In [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview#Request_Headers) it is said, that ip cannot be changed. I thought, that it means i can't change manually ip in HTTP header somehow, but i still can use proxy.

However, i want to know exactly, is it possible to fetch url via proxy on appengine or not and stop breaking my head :).

Comment: possible duplicate of [URLFetch behind a Proxy Server on App Engine Production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799886/urlfetch-behind-a-proxy-server-on-app-engine-production)

Comment: @Wooble thanks for link. But i think it doesn't answers my question. I don't have access to proxy and can't modify its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug in the App-Engine that is mentioned here

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=544

the ticket is closed but the bug is still there as far as I can tell (on SDK 1.9.8)

people have written some code/patches for the Java and Python engines that I haven't tried yet